# Reading an array of integers from a binary file

Tags: c++, for-loop, binary

I am trying to read a binary file into an array of 16-bit integers. I used a for loop to read the data and it works properly. This is how I read the file:

```
 int L = (End-Start)/2;;
 int16_t* I = new int16_t[L];
 int16_t s;

 for(int i=1; i<=L; i++)
 {
     inFile.read((char*)&I[i], sizeof(s));
 }
```

I was wondering if there is any way that I can read the whole array without using for loop?

Comment: arrays start at index 0, not 1 in your loop you are accsessing one index after the end of the array

Comment: Note this code (also in answer below) is still undefined behavior!

Comment: Is my answer enough clear for you ?

Comment: Why do you need the loop?  Array slots are contiguous by definition.  One block read will suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you do not wanted

> ```
> for(int i=1; i<=L; i++)
> ```

but

```
for(int i=0; i<L; i++)
```

because the first index in an array is 0, not 1.

> I was wondering if there is any way that I can read the whole array without using for loop?

you can replace :

> ```
> for(int i=0; i<L; i++)
> {
>     inFile.read((char*)&I[i], sizeof(s));
> }
> ```

by :

```
inFile.read((char*)I, sizeof(*I)*L);
```

If your loop reads well the integers the line above will do too, else the two ways will have the same error (for instance about the endianness).

I recommend you to not use uppercase character to start the name of a local variable and to let that for the global variables, this is a very common practice to help to read C sources.

The variable *s* (e.g. `int16_t s;`) is useless so I removed it.

`sizeof(*I)` values the size of an element of *I*, that form allows to not depends on the type *I* point to and to stay valid even you modify it.

Comment: I used the code you suggested but I get the error: "Unhandled exception at 0x77c115fe in project.exe: 0x0000005: Access violation.

Comment: @MahshadJavidan are you sure you get exactly my code to replace your loop ? What is the value of *L* ?

Comment: yes I had tried that before and I got the same error. the value of L is 153600.

Comment: @MahshadJavidan the other answer you accepted does exactely the same as mine, `I`and `&I[0]` is the same, and `sizeof(*I)` is the same as `sizeof(int16_t)`

Comment: Yes I know! and it makes sense based on Thomas's explanations because they both point to the first element of the array. But I still don't understand why I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the read operation to one statement:

```
int16_t* I = new int16_t[L];
inFile.read((char*)&I[0], L * sizeof(int16_t));
```

There is no need for a `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Thomas Matthews. it seems your code works correctly. can you explain why we should use (char*)&I[0] ?? because I had this impression that it may only reads the first element of array I.

Comment: It's a habit from being MISRA compliant.  The `(char *)` is to convert the starting address to something that `read` can use.  The `&I[0]` explicitly returns the address to the first element in the array.  You could simplify to `(char *) I`, since `I` points to the first element of the array (thus containing the address of the first element).

Comment: Remember, the second parameter of `read` is the quantity, in units of `char`.  The `sizeof` operator returns the size of a `int16_t` in `char`s.  The `L * sizeof(int16_t)` is the size of the array (`L`) times the size of an array slot (`sizeof(int16_t)`), thus calculating the total size of the array in `char`s.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. but I still get the errorr: "Unhandled exception at 0x77c115fe in project.exe: 0x0000005: Access violation" when I use `(char*)I` instead of `(char*)&I[0]`.

Comment: You could add a temporary pointer:  `char * p = (char *) I; infile.read(p, L*sizeof(int16_t));`  This will allow you to compare the value in `p` versus the value in `I`.  They should both be the same.  Use a debugger.